# FabricJs - Scale/Resize All Objects And Center Them Vertically

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, scaletransform

I have an issue with rescaling objects from a canvas, so they perfectly fit the width of the new resized canvas, and center them on Y axis in the middle of the canvas.
 A code posted on stackoverflow helps with resizing as long as you leave the objects in the same "top" position (and do not force them to align middle).

Here is the code I am using, and works perfect:
function zoomIt(new_width,new_height,old_canvas_width,old_canvas_height) {

```
    if(old_canvas_width!=new_width) //if the new canvas width is different than the old width, we need to resize all objects within the canvas
    { 
        var factor=new_width/old_canvas_width; //find multiplier for scalling
        var extra_top=(new_height-old_canvas_height)/2;

        var objects = canvas.getObjects();

        for (var i in objects) {
            var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;

            var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
            var left = objects[i].left;
            var top = objects[i].top;


            var tempScaleX = scaleX * factor;
            var tempScaleY = scaleY * factor;
            var tempLeft = left * factor;
            var tempTop = top * factor;

            objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
            objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
            objects[i].left = tempLeft;
            objects[i].top = tempTop + extra_top;


            objects[i].setCoords();
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
        canvas.calcOffset();
    }
}
```

I have added:
var extra_top=(new_height-old_canvas_height)/2;

I calculate the difference between new height of canvas and old one, split by 2 and try to add this new value to each object TOP position.
 But the results are not what I want. They are not centered vertically.

Can anybody help with this issue?

Here is the original canvas (1280x720)
 [image: Original Canvas - 1280x720]

Here is the current resized canvas (720x1280). Please note any size should work, currently I test with 16:9 and 9:16, but the size is not really relevant:
[image]

And here is how it should actually look like:
[image]

The problem with my approach of simply adding extra_top is that if I try to resize back to 1280x720 (to original canvas size) everything is misaligned (when actually is should be identical to when it was not resized).

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit stupid, but the solution was super simple...
The extra_top variable was not calculate correctly.

We need to take in account the scale factor.
So the correct extra_top value is:

**var extra_top=(new_height-old_canvas_height*factor)/2;**

And it works perfect.